# In typescript, how to convert from union of base interfaces to union of extended interfaces

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'm fairly new to typescript and am stuck trying to wrap my head around how to properly use union types. I'm working on an app that will receive a collection of base-structures from one api, and then augment them with data from other apis/state. Both the base set of interfaces and the augmented interfaces could be strongly typed, and so I'd like to leverage that.

What I want to accomplish:

- strongly typed base type as a union of the set of base interfaces
- strongly typed 'decorated' type as a union of the set of decorated interfaces
- method to convert between them

Errors occur at the conversion step, as it seems typescript doesn't know that the functions being used to decorate are following the rules defined in the interfaces. I've put together a minimal example case below:

```
type PetKind = 'dog' | 'cat'

interface BasePetInterface {
  kind: PetKind
  name: string
}

interface BaseDog extends BasePetInterface {
  kind: 'dog'
}

interface BaseCat extends BasePetInterface {
  kind: 'cat'
}

type BasePet = BaseDog | BaseCat

function getFluffy(p: BasePet): boolean {
  if (p.kind === 'dog') return true
  if (p.kind === 'cat') return false
}

interface FluffyDog extends BaseDog {
  fluffy: true
}

interface NotFluffyCat extends BaseCat {
  fluffy: false
}

type Pet = FluffyDog | NotFluffyCat

function getPet(p: BasePet): Pet {
  return {
    ...p,
    fluffy: getFluffy(p)
  }
    /* error here ->
       severity: 'Error'
       message: 'Type '{ fluffy: boolean; kind: "dog"; name: string; } 
       | { fluffy: boolean; kind: "cat"; name: string; }' is not 
       assignable to type 'Pet'.
       Type '{ fluffy: boolean; kind: "dog"; name: string; }' is not 
       assignable to type 'Pet'.
       Type '{ fluffy: boolean; kind: "dog"; name: string; }' is not 
       assignable to type 'NotFluffyCat'.
       Types of property 'fluffy' are incompatible.
       Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.'
}
```

The above 'fluffy' is contrived - in the actual app these are variables that may depend on other pieces of state. They may be pre-determined for some full types and conditional in others.

Is there a way to handle this? or perhaps is there a better pattern for dealing with collections of related base and decorated interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.'

This is just typescript figuring out that not all combintations of `BasePet` + `boolean` match your (constrained) `Pet`.

If all combinations were valid `Pet`s you would not get the error.

## Summary

What you are doing is effectively:

```
type True = true;
type False = false; 
type Bool = true | false; 

declare let x: Bool;
declare let y: False;
y = x; // Error: same error as you are getting
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense - because typescript is only aware that getFluffy returns a boolean, it's not aware that it's returning a boolean conditionally based on the type passed in.

Is it possible to do this? Or is this approach of working with constrained union types not something that's typically done?